# C++ variable overloading ambiguity

Tags: c++

For the following line of code:

`for (int i = 1; i <= var; i++) {
double inc = (14.0) - double(ceil(log10(i)))};`

I keep getting the error

`Overloading ambiguity between "std::log10(double)" and "std::log10(float)"`

I've also tried casting both `inc` and `ceil(log10(i))`  to float to no avail. Thoughts?

Comment: Thanks, that helped!

Answer (score 2):

What makes you think casting `inc` or `ceil` will help? The compiler is telling you that it can't figure out whether you want `log10(float)` or `log10(double)`. You need to make that clear to the compiler

```
double inc = (14.0) - double(ceil(log10((float)i)));
```

or

```
double inc = (14.0) - double(ceil(log10((double)i)));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Overloading ambiguity between "`std::log10(double)`" and "`std::log10(float)`"
                                           ^^^^^^                     ^^^^^
```

As @John3136 commented the error is referring to the input of the `log10` function. In this case that is the `i` variable which is an `int` type. Since, `int` is neither a `float` or a `double` and both conversions are equally viable the compiler doesn't know which to choose. Therefore, you have to explicitly select one. For example:

```
std::log10(static_cast<float>(i));
```